# Criticism of proof attempt: Maillet's Conjecture

Tags: solution-verification, prime-numbers

I'm going to start out by saying that the present proof is not completely mine: it is a result obtained by the collaboration with a mathematician with whom I was in contact. This matematician unfortunately passed away a few months ago.

We were working on a paper focused on the study of a pair of topologies defined on the sets $\mathbb{N}$ of the positive natural numbers and on the set $\mathbb{P}$ of the odd prime numbers. The proof I'm presenting here (in a slight concise manner) is the very first important result obtained from that theory.
I just would like to know if this proof is correct. I mean, we reviewed the proof so many times that in our opinion it is correct. But still, I'm perfectly aware that solving a conjecture about prime numbers is not a thing of every day, and there are lots of far more brilliant minds that have worked on this than me.

If there is no error, I feel compelled to publish the article in memory of the deceased mathematician.

I am aware that requesting a Proof Verification of open problems on this site is not the best thing to do: accordingly to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19652/proof-verification-of-open-problems?noredirect=1&lq=1) old post, for example, *"the fact that the user seeks validation of a solution of a major open problem on a site like this one is enough evidence; no further consideration of the proof is needed"* and I 99% agree with that. The fact is: I'm asking here because I'm not actually a researcher, but only another one of the many math enthusiast out there, and unfortunately I don't know anyone to talk with who can be interested in the argument; so I chose to take the risk and ask. I apologize in advance if this turns out to be only a waste of time (which I hope it isn't).

**Conjecture's statement**

*Every even number can be expressed as the difference of two prime numbers (Maillet's Conjecture)*

**Proof (attempt)**

Let $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ the set of positive integers and $\mathbb{P} = \{3, 5, 7, ...\}$ the set of odd prime numbers.

For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ let $O_m = \{p \in \mathbb{P} : p + 2m \notin \mathbb{P}\}$ and let $H_m = \{p \in \mathbb{P} : p + 2m \in \mathbb{P}\} = \mathbb{P} - O_m$ the complement of $O_m$ (respect to $\mathbb{P}$). (as a side note, $O_m$ are the subbasic open sets of the topology defined for $\mathbb{P}$ the study of which is one of the subject of our paper)

Similarly, for each $p \in \mathbb{P}$ let $O^*_p = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : p + 2m \notin \mathbb{P}\}$ and let $H^*_p = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : p + 2m \in \mathbb{P}\} = \mathbb{N} - O^*_p$ the complement of $O^*_p$ (respect to $\mathbb{N}$). (as a side note, $O^*_p$ are the subbasic open sets of the topology defined for $\mathbb{N}$ the study of which is one of the subject of our paper)

Basic properties

1. $p \in O_m \Leftrightarrow m \in O^*_p$ and $p \in H_m \Leftrightarrow m \in H^*_p$ (it follows directly from definitions)
2. $O^*_p$ contains infinite elements for each $p$ (it follows from the fact that composite numbers are infinite)
3. $H^*_p$ contains infinite elements for each $p$ (it follows from the fact that prime numbers are infinite)
4. $O_m$ contains infinite elements for each $m$ (it follows from the existence of prime gaps of arbitrary length)
5. The Conjecture's statement is equivalent to the fact that $H_m \neq \emptyset$ for each $m$ (indeed, for a given even number $2k$, if $H_k \neq \emptyset$ then there exists a prime $p \in H_k$ and, by definition, this means that $q = p + 2k$ is also a prime number)

Let $Z = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : H_m = \emptyset\}$

**Claim** $Z = \displaystyle\bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{P}}{O^*_p}$. Indeed, $m \in Z \Leftrightarrow H_m = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow O_m = \mathbb{P} \Leftrightarrow \forall p \in \mathbb{P} : p \in O_m \Leftrightarrow \forall p \in \mathbb{P} : m \in O^*_p \Leftrightarrow m \in \displaystyle\bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{P}}{O^*_p}$.

Suppose now $m \notin Z$ and let $A_m = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m} {O^*_q}$, $B_m =\displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in O_m} {O^*_q}$ and $C_m =\displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q }$.

**Claim** $A_m = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {O^*_q} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_m \subseteq O_k\}$. Indeed $k \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {O^*_q} \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in H_m : k \in O^*_q \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in H_m : q \in O_k \Leftrightarrow H_m \subseteq O_k$

**Claim** $B_m = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in O_m } {O^*_q} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : O_m \subseteq O_k\}$. Indeed $k \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in O_m } {O^*_q} \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in O_m : k \in O^*_q \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in O_m : q \in O_k \Leftrightarrow O_m \subseteq O_k$

**Claim** $C_m = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_m \subseteq H_k\}$. Indeed $k \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q} \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in H_m : k \in H^*_q \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in H_m : q \in H_k \Leftrightarrow H_m \subseteq H_k$

We have $A_m \cap B_m = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m} {O^*_q} \cap \displaystyle  \bigcap_{q \in O_m} {O^*_q} = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m \cup O_m } {O^*_q} = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{P}} {O^*_q} = Z$

and therefore $(A_m \cap B_m) \cap C_m = Z \cap \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q} { }^{(1)}$.

Secondly, $B_m \cap C_m = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in O_m } {O^*_q} \cap \bigcap_{q \in H_m} {H^*_q} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : O_m \subseteq O_k\} \cap \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_m \subseteq H_k\} = \{ {k \in \mathbb{N} : O_m = O_k } \}$

and so $A_m \cap (B_m \cap C_m) = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_m \subseteq O_k\} \cap \{ {k \in \mathbb{N} : O_m = O_k } \} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_k \subseteq O_m\} \cap \{ {k \in \mathbb{N} : O_m = O_k } \} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_k \subseteq O_k\} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_k = \emptyset\} = Z$

and therefore $A_m \cap (B_m \cap C_m) = Z { }^{(2)}$

From (1) and (2) we obtain $Z \cap \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q} = Z$  for every $m \notin Z$. In other words, $\forall m \notin Z$ : $Z \subseteq \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q}$.

Furthermore, it is also true that $Z \subseteq \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q}$ if $m \in Z$ because in that case $\displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q} = \mathbb{N}$ (recall that $m \in Z$ means $H_m = \emptyset$ and $\displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_m \subseteq H_k\})$.

So we have $\forall m \in \mathbb{N} : Z \subseteq \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q} \Rightarrow Z \subseteq\displaystyle \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} {\displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in H_m } {H^*_q}} = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} {H_m}} {H^*_q} = \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{P}} {H^*_q}$

since $\displaystyle \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} {H_m} = \mathbb{P}$ (indeed, if $\displaystyle \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} {H_m} \subsetneqq \mathbb{P}$ then $\displaystyle \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} {O_m} \neq \emptyset$, but $q \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} {O_m} \Leftrightarrow \forall m \in \mathbb{N} : q \in O_m \Leftrightarrow \forall m \in \mathbb{N} : m \in O^*_q \Leftrightarrow O^*_q = \mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow H^*_q = \emptyset$ which is absurd because prime numbers are infinite).

Finally, $m \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{P}} {H^*_q} \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in \mathbb{P} : m \in H^*_q \Leftrightarrow \forall q \in \mathbb{P} : q \in H_m \Leftrightarrow H_m = \mathbb{P} \Leftrightarrow O_m = \emptyset$ which is absurd because of the existence of prime gaps of arbitrary length.

We deduce that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{P}} {H^*_q} = \emptyset$ and thus, $Z = \emptyset$.

Comment: The proof is long and not easy to follow , so it boils down to use this site as a proof-checking machine. In fact, there is an even stronger conjecture , namely that every even number occurs as a prime gap. Here we "only" demand that for every even $n$ there exists a prime $p$ such that $p+n$ is prime as well. But the infinite many primes and the arbitary large gaps alone do not ensure this. Which arguments do you have beyond that ?

Comment: What happens if you replace prime numbers with squares? You still have $O_m$, $O_p^*$ and $H_p^*$ each infinite, but not every even number is difference of two squares.

Comment: Hi Peter, first of all thank you for your interest. I'm sorry, I tried to condense the proof but, still, it is quite long. You are right by saying that the de Polignac conjecture is stronger than the Maillet's Conjecture (as a side note, the de Polignac conjecture is equivalent to the fact that $H_m \cup O_{m-1} \cup ... \cup O_1 \neq \emptyset$ for each $m$). The infinite many primes and the arbitary large gaps are not really used in the proof, I inserted them in order to clarify the above definitions. The only property that matter is the first, a sort of "inversion" formula

Comment: (...) a sort of "inversion" formula used to go from $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and viceversa. In topological terms, $Z = \emptyset$ is equivalent to the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ (with the topology generated by $O^*_p$ as a subbase of open sets) has no generic point (that is, points whose singleton is dense).

Comment: Is it true that what you actually prove is that for sets $E$ and $P$, if there for every $e \in E$ there are infinitely many $p \in P$ s.t. $e + p \notin P$, and also for every $p \in P$ there are both infinitely many numbers $e \in E$ s.t. $p + e \in P$ and $p + e \notin P$, then every number from $E$ is difference of two numbers from $P$?

Comment: I don't think this is a good site for the review of lengthy, complex proofs.  In any case, it would help if you clearly stated the properties of primes which play a role in this argument.  As has been remarked, there are plenty of sets of natural numbers which satisfy similar crude statistics but for which the analogous claim is false.

Comment: As a general matter, I suggest sending the full (non "condensed") argument to your colleagues, or to the colleagues of your collaborator.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the proof I posted here.

I'm posting here the error hoping this can be useful for others.

The following equality is false in general:

$\{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_k \subseteq O_m\} \cap \{ {k \in \mathbb{N} : O_m = O_k } \} = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_k \subseteq O_k\}$

For example, using the squares instead of primes, we have $H_1 \subseteq O_1$ (since $H_1 = \emptyset$) so that $1 \in \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_k \subseteq O_k\}$

We also have $1 \in \{k \in \mathbb{N} : H_k \subseteq O_8\}$ but

$1 \notin \{ {k \in \mathbb{N} : O_8 = O_k } \}$

I would like to thanks everyone who spent some time reading this. I hope I haven't wasted too much of your time.